# Looping the difference between 168 values

Tags: r, time-series

I am working with a peculiar time series data and instead of knowing the lag values such as (lag 1 or lag 168) I would like to know if its possible to obtain the difference each 168 values. Basically I have an hourly cumulative production time series data and I am interested in knowing the total amount of sells each week.

```
yweekly=yt168-yt0
```

I tried:

```
i<-0
j<-0
for (i in nrow(DT)){
    aux[j]<-DT$value[i+167]-DT$value[i]
    i<-i+168
}
```

Final Solution:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(DT)){
  diff168[j]<-DT$value[i+167]-DT$value[i]
  i<-i+1
  j<-j+1
}
```

However when I do that I got the vector aux as a NA_real_ vector

I hope that you can help me

EDIT: SOLVED

Comment: do you want to calculate the difference t and t+1 value ?

Comment: I want to calculate the difference between t+168 and t0, t+336 and t+168 etc...

Answer (score 4):

Try using command `diff` with `lag=168` like this:

```
x<-c(1:1000)
diff(x,lag=168)
```

If you want to keep only a difference after each 168 values (if I well understand your code):

```
x<-runif(1000,10,100)

all_diff<-diff(x,lag=168)

all_diff[seq(1,length(all_diff),by=168)]
```

Comment: Hi! if I do that I obtain an output vector of 2538 values which is not the thing that I want:

> set.seed(123)
> aux2<-c(1:1000)
> aux3<-diff(x, lag=168)
> length(aux3)
[1] 2538

I need to make the difference between value 168-0, 336-168, 504-336.

With the thing that I would like to run the output vector should be shorter than the original one.

If I have hourly data from one year my output vector would be with length 52 isn't it?

Comment: Did you try also the second part of the Answer?